# transition delete after i open the navbar. what happen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I have a navbar opening div when i hover on it, it shows a tip(something like that) and when i hover on tip it will disappear.
the tip has got a transition But when i open and close the navbar the transition will deleted and when i hover on tip it wont disappear.
its the code:

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("navbar-content").style.marginLeft = "60px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.726)";
    document.getElementById("menu-icon-tip").style.opacity = "0";
}
/* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 and the left margin of the page content to 0, and the background color of body to white */
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("navbar-content").style.marginLeft = "-200px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(51, 51, 51)";
    document.getElementById("menu-icon-tip").style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById("menu-icon-tip").style.transition = "opacity 1s";
}
```

```css
body{
background : #000;
}
.menu-icon {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 20px 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    transition: background 1s;
}
.menu-icon-tip {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 110px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 3px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 140%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    font-family: menu;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.menu-icon-tip::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -7px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #555;
    border-top: none ;
}

.menu-icon:hover > .menu-icon-tip {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.rect-menu {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 11px;
}

.menu-icon-rect-1 {
    width: 65px;
    height: 9px;
    background: rgb(196, 196, 196);
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin: 3px 1px;
}

.menu-icon-rect-2 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 9px;
    background: rgb(196, 196, 196);
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin: 3px 1px;
}

.menu-icon-rect-3 {
    width: 45px;
    height: 9px;
    background: rgb(196, 196, 196);
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin: 3px 1px;
}

.circle-menu {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: -36.5px;
}

.menu-icon-circle {
    width:  9px;
    height: 9px;
    background: rgb(196, 196, 196);
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.menu-icon:hover .menu-icon-rect-1 {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.menu-icon:hover .menu-icon-rect-2 {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.menu-icon:hover .menu-icon-rect-3 {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.menu-icon:hover .menu-icon-circle {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.navbar {
    height: 100%;
    /* 100% Full-height */
    width: 0;
    /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
    position: fixed;
    /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1;
    /* Stay on top */
    top: 0;
    /* Stay at the top */
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    /* Black*/
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    padding-top: 60px;
    /* Place content 60px from the top */
    transition: 1s;
    /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
    font-family: menu;
}

.navbar-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    left: -70px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    transition: 1s;
}

.navbar-content a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.menu-close-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    color: rgb(207, 207, 207);
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar" id="navbar">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="menu-close-btn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
                <div id="navbar-content" class="navbar-content">
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                    <a href="">item2</a>
                    <a href="">item3</a>
                    <a href="">item4</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-icon" onclick="openNav()">
                <span class="menu-icon-tip" id="menu-icon-tip">open Navigation bar</span>
                <div class="rect-menu">
                    <div class="menu-icon-rect-1"></div>
                    <div class="menu-icon-rect-2"></div>
                    <div class="menu-icon-rect-3"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="circle-menu">
                    <div class="menu-icon-circle"></div>
                    <div class="menu-icon-circle"></div>
                    <div class="menu-icon-circle"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

what can i do?
[it is the video](https://gofile.io/d/9PJ30u)

Comment: I'm not really understanding your issue. What do you mean by "transition delete"?

Comment: see the video you will understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are overriding the transition.
use `.active` class and toggle this class

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("navbar-content").style.marginLeft = "60px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.726)";
      const menuIconTip = document.getElementById("menu-icon-tip");
    menuIconTip.classList.add('active');
}
/* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 and the left margin of the page content to 0, and the background color of body to white */
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("navbar-content").style.marginLeft = "-200px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(51, 51, 51)";
    const menuIconTip = document.getElementById("menu-icon-tip");
    menuIconTip.classList.remove('active');
}
```

```css
body{
background : #000;
}
.menu-icon {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 20px 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    transition: background 1s;
}
.menu-icon-tip {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 110px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 3px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 140%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    font-family: menu;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.menu-icon-tip.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu-icon-tip::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -7px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #555;
    border-top: none ;
}

.menu-icon:hover > .menu-icon-tip {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.rect-menu {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 11px;
}

.menu-icon-rect-1 {
    width: 65px;
    height: 9px;
    background: rgb(196, 196, 196);
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin: 3px 1px;
}

.menu-icon-rect-2 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 9px;
    background: rgb(196, 196, 196);
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin: 3px 1px;
}

.menu-icon-rect-3 {
    width: 45px;
    height: 9px;
    background: rgb(196, 196, 196);
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin: 3px 1px;
}

.circle-menu {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: -36.5px;
}

.menu-icon-circle {
    width:  9px;
    height: 9px;
    background: rgb(196, 196, 196);
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.menu-icon:hover .menu-icon-rect-1 {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.menu-icon:hover .menu-icon-rect-2 {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.menu-icon:hover .menu-icon-rect-3 {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.menu-icon:hover .menu-icon-circle {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.navbar {
    height: 100%;
    /* 100% Full-height */
    width: 0;
    /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
    position: fixed;
    /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1;
    /* Stay on top */
    top: 0;
    /* Stay at the top */
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    /* Black*/
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    padding-top: 60px;
    /* Place content 60px from the top */
    transition: 1s;
    /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
    font-family: menu;
}

.navbar-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    left: -70px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    transition: 1s;
}

.navbar-content a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.menu-close-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    color: rgb(207, 207, 207);
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar" id="navbar">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="menu-close-btn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
                <div id="navbar-content" class="navbar-content">
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                    <a href="">item2</a>
                    <a href="">item3</a>
                    <a href="">item4</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-icon" onclick="openNav()">
                <span class="menu-icon-tip" id="menu-icon-tip">open Navigation bar</span>
                <div class="rect-menu">
                    <div class="menu-icon-rect-1"></div>
                    <div class="menu-icon-rect-2"></div>
                    <div class="menu-icon-rect-3"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="circle-menu">
                    <div class="menu-icon-circle"></div>
                    <div class="menu-icon-circle"></div>
                    <div class="menu-icon-circle"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding your css transition with your javascript

You should remove any style modification you're applying on `.menu-icon-tip`

```
document.getElementById("menu-icon-tip").style.opacity = "0";
```

And

```
  document.getElementById("menu-icon-tip").style.opacity = "1";
  document.getElementById("menu-icon-tip").style.transition = "opacity 1s";
```

They're useless and are messing with your animations.